# Computing the matrix of $Tp(x) = p'(x) + x^2 p''(x)$ relative to the basis $\{1, x, x^2\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Show that the operator $T \colon P_2(\mathbb{R}) \to P_2(\mathbb{R})$ given by
>   $$
>   Tp(x) = p'(x) + x^2 p''(x)
> $$
>   is a linear operator.
>
> Compute the matrix $[T]_{B,B}$ of $T$ relative to the standard basis $B = \{1, x, x^2\}$ for $P_2(\mathbb{R})$.

So I know that a polynomial in $P_2(\mathbb{R})$ is of the form $ax^2 + bx + c$, and $P'(x) = 2ax + b$, $P''(x) = 2a$.

So $Tp(x) = 2ax+b + 2ax^2 = b + 2ax + 2ax^2$.

But I am having trouble expressing it in terms of a matrix.

Just to make sure I understand it, I have tried the question with a new basis $B=(1,x,x^2+x+\frac{1}{2}$) and I get the matrix:

$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        0 & 1 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 2 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

Applying the operator $x^2+x+\frac{1}{2}$ gives me $2x^2+2x+1$, which is 2 lots of the basis.
Comments:
-A linear operator is always unique.
-Since the only basis that changed was the last one, that means I can borrow the first 2 columns from my first matrix.

Comment: Fixed. The resulting matrix will be 3 by 3 correct, and the diagonals will be b,2a,2a and 0 everywhere else?

Comment: The matrix is correct. But about your comments, if $T(x)$ (here $x$ is a basis's member) had a term of $x^2$, then the second column of these two matrices would be different. So, your second comment is not necessary true. About the first comment, please give more explanations.

Comment: The first comment I know it from a theorem, I haven't studied the proof yet. And I see what you mean about my second comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have the operator $T \colon P_2(\mathbb{R}) \to P_2(\mathbb{R})$ given by
$$
  Tp(x) = p'(x) + x^2 p''(x)
$$ and basis $\beta=\{1,x,x^2\}$. Now first consider $p(x)=1$, from the basis. Then $p'(x)=0=p''(x)$. So $T(p(x))=0=0\times1+0\times x+0\times x^2$. Similarly for $p(x)=x$ and $p(x)=x^2$, we get $T(p(x))=1+0\times x+0\times x^2$ and $T(p(x))=0\times1+2\times x+2\times x^2$ respectively. Hence ,
$$[T]_\beta=\begin{bmatrix}0&1&0\\ 0&0&2\\ 0&0&2\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Makes sense now. Thanks. I have done edited and answered a similar question with a different basis.  Please check and verify. Thanks

Comment: You are good. well done @anna_xox

Answer (score 2):

To show the linearity, you just need to show $T(p(x)+aq(x))=T(p(x))+aT(q(x))$ which is concluded easily since derivative operator is a linear one.

To find the matrix of operator according to the given basis, you need to compute the operator on the basis's members and make the answers as a linear combination of the basis's members.

$T(1)=0$ and so the first column of the matrix is $\begin{pmatrix}0\\ 0\\ 0\end{pmatrix}$.

$T(x)=1$ and so the second column of the matrix is $\begin{pmatrix}1\\ 0\\ 0\end{pmatrix}$.

$T(x^2)=2x+2x^2$ and so the third column of the matrix is $\begin{pmatrix}0\\ 2\\ 2\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: Makes sense now. Thanks. I have done edited and added a similar question with a different basis for  some practice.  Please check my answer. Thanks