# Linear transformation, change of basis, how to check answer

Tags: linear-transformations, change-of-basis

[image]

Can anyone verify I have done this problem correctly and is there any way to check my answer for part c? I was thinking when I transform this basis {1, x, x^2+ x + 1/2) I get 0(1) 1(x) and 2(x^2+x+1/2) which to me seems to give me the final matrix.

Comment: In part b, it should be $T(1), T(x), T(x^2)$, and not $T(p(1)), T(p(x)), T(p(x^2))$.  Otherwise everything looks good.  As for a way to check part c, why not figure out $[T]_{B',B'}$ the same way you found $[T]_{B,B}$ in part b?

Comment: You may see here the same question. It seems that you are studying a same book. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1822671/computing-the-matrix-of-tpx-px-x2-px-relative-to-the-basis-1/1822708#1822708